# Accident probability

Tags: probability

Need a help with checking these calculations , i am so confused on problem with at least 2 accidents and suspect i am wrong .

A small tourist resort has a weekend traffic problem and is considering whether or
not to provide emergency services to help mitigate the congestion that results from
an accident or breakdown. Past records show that the probability of a breakdown or
an accident on any given day of a four-day weekend is 0.25.

As part of its contingency planning, the resort needs to know:
(a) The probability that a weekend will have no accidents
(b) The probability that a weekend will have at least two accidents
[image: problem 1]

Comment: You've calculated probabililty of **exactly** 2 days with acicdents. To get prob. of **at least** 2 days with acicdents think of which number of days is **at least 2** in your setting. Is it 3 days? 1 day? 15 days?

Comment: the setting is at least 2 accidents on a 4 days weekend( bit odd 4 days weekend?) I messaged you on FB , maybe you could help me with understanding .. I wouldn't even check but came across answers and trying to figure it out but no progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: In your setting **at least 2 days** is 2, 3 or 4 days.